# Reports in PHP using stored procedure

Tags: php, mysql, stored-procedures, mysqli, report

How to make reports in php using stored procedure? Based on what i have searched, stored procedure uses mysqli not mysql. So i am confused if this is possible or not. Can you give me an example on how to implement this one?

Comment: What do you mean by "reports" exactly?

Comment: reports like those in vb6...

Comment: Can you clarify what those are exactly? Also, how to stored procedures play into this as a requirement?

Comment: @Pekka웃: I need to use stored procedure in my database to view reports e.g. list of supplliers, products, call them from my php script. I hope i made myself clear to you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to call a stored procedure in MySQL, both `mysql` and `mysqli` can do it.  Although, I'd recommend `mysqli` regardless, as it is just better (hence the `i`; 'improved'; I think).

You would call a stored procedure like you call any other SQL statement in PHP:

```
mysqli_query($link, "CALL Procedure('$strVar', $intVar, etc.)");
```

While my example uses `mysqli_query`, `mysql_query` would work just as well.

It is not possible to create stored procedures from inside PHP, because while PHP does have a `multi_query()` function on its `mysqli` object, it only allows `;` as a delimiter.  And that's bad, because you are going to need that *inside* your stored procedure, but PHP will execute them as separate queries.

A stored procedure in MySQL as an example:

```
DELIMITER $$
DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS `Procedure`$$
CREATE PROCEDURE `Procedure` (
    IN `userid` INT
)
    IF EXISTS (SELECT 1
        FROM `users`
        WHERE `user_id` = `userid`)
    THEN
        SELECT `user_name`
        FROM `users`
        WHERE `user_id` = `userid`;
    ELSE
        SELECT `user_name` = 'No such user';
    END IF;
END $$
```

Notice how you are required to rename the delimiter (the standard delimiter is `;`), because it is used inside the stored procedures (because a procedure is a multitude of queries and must be separated by such a delimiter).  `$$` is the usually recommended renaming of the delimiter.

If I were to run this SQL from inside PHP, using `multi_query()`, it would split my queries by the `;` resulting in five queries, that would all have syntax errors (because they are fragments).

So, to create stored procedures, write a .sql script for the purpose.  Then run your script from a terminal:

```
$ mysql --user="$USER" --password="$PASSWORD" $DB < $FILE
```

If you want to know more about stored procedures in MySQL, I'd recommend you search the web, there are plenty of excellent tutorials.  But you do not require any special magic to call them from PHP compared to regular SQL statements.